# AsyncHttpClient no ejecuta onSucces ni onFailure

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

Ejecuto el método DNITaxistes pero al hacer la llamada no me ejecuta el código del `onSuccess` y tampoco el del `onFailure`, directamente sale del método. El método buscarTaxista ejecuta otra llamada asíncrona. Alguna solución?

```
 public void DNITaxistes() {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(URL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            JSONArray dniTaxistes;
            String strResponseBody = new String(responseBody);

            try {
                dniTaxistes = new JSONArray(strResponseBody);
                for(int i=0; i < dniTaxistes.length(); i ++){
                    DNITaxistaTemporal = dniTaxistes.getString(i);
                    Log.d("DNI TAXISTA: ",""+ DNITaxistaTemporal);
                    buscarTaxista();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("error",""+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Log.d("ERROR STATUS:"," "+ statusCode);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Revisa que en realidad estés llamando el método DNITaxistes() en realidad siempre debe llamar uno u otro método @moraa

Answer (score 0):

Una razón por la cual no llama `onSuccess()` o `onFailure()` es porque en realidad no estas llamando el método o realizando la petición con `AsyncHttpClient`, **debe necesariamente llamar a alguno de los dos**.

Aunque no tengas conexión a Internet esto llamaría el método `onFailure()`

Asegura tener estos import:

```
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
```

Comment: He pasado el debug y llega a entrar hasta el client.get(URL,...) pero el siguiente paso sale fuera. En el el metodo onFailure tengo puesto un Log y no lo ejecuta.

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código y  obtengo los DNI en onSuccess 65321578T, 65321489G, 32256894r . Asegiura tienes los import que comento en la respuesta

Comment: Si, tengo todos los imports que dices. Por Postman me los devuelve bien pero el problema debe estar en Android.

Comment: No me digas que estas usando el emulador, quita un momento buscarTaxista(); y prueba nuevamente, revisa si entra

Comment: Si, utilizo el emulador de Android. Con el debug ejecuta lo mismo que anteriormente. Puede ser problema del emulador entonces?

Comment: Definitivamente, crea otro emulador o usa un AVD, te comento que yo pruebo la petición a la API y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78112/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-moraa).